# How can I calculate the position of a DOM element from Google Chrome content scripts

Tags: dom, scripting, google-chrome

I am writing a chrome extension and from the content script I want to calculate the absolute position of a DOM element. But from within content script, if i try to access `offsetHeight`, `offsetWidth`, `offsetTop`, `offsetParent`, etc, I get `null`. I guess content scripts don't have access to those DOM properties.

Is there a way/workaround, i can find those properties?

Answer (score 0):

It should work great, how are you accessing it?

```
// Should be something like this:
var height = document.getElementById('mydiv').offsetHeight;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.offsetHeight

Comment: actually chorme does not understand embed that well. :( ..embed.offsetHeight is null but it gives me embed.height. 
So i kind of had to work around .. created a div on top of the embed and calculate the position of that div.
Worked.
Thanks for the help.